# mySQL view to show distict value and all pertaining rows beneath it

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I am using mySQL.  I have a table that is updated everyday based on our sku.  The sku has duplicate values because there is a pricing tier associated with it.  I need to create a view that will show all the rows but only 1 sku and the associated sku rows beneath it so i can export everyday for an update in magento.  Magento does not allow duplicate sku's during an import.  Here is an example:

sku             _tier_price_qty _tier_price_price
013964223286    10              1
                50              1
                100             1
9332153001025   5               1
                25              1
                50              1
9332153001032   5               1
                25              1
                50              1
9332153001063   5               1
                25              1
                50              1
9332153001049   5               1
                25              1
                50              1
640420002569    5               1
                25              1
                50              1
640420002538    5               1
                25              1
                50              1
640420002521    5               1
                25              1
                50              1

Comment: If your intent is to use the result to import into another application, then maybe disassociating the quantity and price from the sku where there are duplicates isn't the best way to handle it. Maybe aggregating the data instead would be better? See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3314bd/2

Comment: So, did any of the answers help solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Although this type of formatting might be better to handle in a reporting application this query should do what you want:

```
select 
    case when x.tier_qty is not null then t.sku else null end tier_qty, 
    t.tier_qty, 
    t.tier_price
from t
left join (
    select sku, min(tier_qty) tier_qty
    from t
    group by sku
) x on t.sku = x.sku and t.tier_qty = x.tier_qty
order by t.sku, t.tier_qty;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3314bd/1

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
select case when (select MIN(tier_qty) from products where sku = o.sku) = tier_qty
            then sku
            else null,
       tier_qty,
       tier_price
from products o
order by sku, tier_qty
```